# How to Use Multiple Conditions In An Update Statement With Zend_Db And QuoteInto

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Using Zend Framework, is there a way to pass multiple conditions to an update statement using the quoteInto method? I've found some references to this problem but I'm looking for a supported way without having to extend Zend_Db or without concatenation.

```
$db = $this->getAdapter();
$data = array('profile_value' => $form['profile_value']);
$where = $db->quoteInto('user_id = ?', $form['id'])
       . $db->quoteInto(' AND profile_key = ?', $key);         
$this->update($data, $where);
```

**References**

- http://blog.motane.lu/2009/05/21/zend_db-quoteinto-with-multiple-arguments/
- http://codeaid.net/php/multiple-parameters-in-zend_db::quoteinto%28%29

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use an `array` type for your `$where` argument. The elements will be combined with the `AND` operator:

```
$where = array();
$where[] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('user_id = ?', $form['id']);
$where[] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('key = ?', $key);
$this->update(array('value' => $form['value']), $where);
```

Comment: how to achieve this if I have OR condition?

Answer (score 16):

Since 1.8 you can use:

```
$where = array(
    'name = ?' => $name,
    'surname = ?' => $surname
);
$db->update($data, $where);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I used `$db->update($data, array('id = ?' => $id);`

Comment: Wish this was documented :-( Still valid in 1.12.x.

Answer (score -2):

Just refreshing the above answer

```
$data = array('value' => $form['value']);
$where = array();
$where[] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('user_id = ?', $form['id']);   
$where[] = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('key = ?', $key);
$this->update($data, $where);
```