# OR clause in Zend DB update?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I'd like to do a Zend db update with an OR clause. What would be the equivalent statement to:

```
UPDATE mail
SET message_read = 1
WHERE id = 5
OR id = 10
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use Multiple Conditions In An Update Statement With Zend_Db And QuoteInto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321504/how-to-use-multiple-conditions-in-an-update-statement-with-zend-db-and-quoteinto)

Comment: @cbuckley This would combine the WHERE using `AND` which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When calling `Zend_Db_Adapter::update()`, multiple `WHERE` conditions will automatically be combined using `AND` (line 698 of Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php in function _whereExpr).

You can get around this by creating your own `Zend_Db_Expr` which you will use as the `WHERE` condition and it will be left untouched.

For example:

```
$where[] = new Zend_Db_Expr(
        $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', 5) . ' OR ' .
        $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', 10)
);

// resulting expression:
//   WHERE (id = 5 OR id = 10)

$table->update($data, $where);
```

If you had additional `WHERE` conditions, they would be combined with the `OR` condition by an `AND`.

Example:

```
$where[] = new Zend_Db_Expr(
        $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', 5) . ' OR ' .
        $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', 10)
);
$where[] = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('type = ?', 'sometype');

// resulting expression:
//   WHERE (id = 5 OR id = 10) AND (type = 'sometype')
```

Answer (score 2):

->where() will add a where clause to the query and will put an 'AND'.  There is an orWhere method that exists to do that.

```
$select = $this->select();
$select->where('id = 5');
$select->orWhere('id = 10');

$this->fetchAll($select);
```